# Implementing joins on multiple collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, mongoose, social-networking

I am trying to create a social networking application which can have connect (followers, following), posts, comments, likes, shares, etc. This is a MVP project, but still i wanted to explore mongoDB for this use case. I am having some doubt regarding the performance of this application.

I have three collection:

- Posts: This is where a new post shall be added. This collection contains all the details related to a post.

  `Schema: 
  const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user_id: String,
    title: String,
    text: String,
    type: { type: String, enum: ["music", "movie", "tv"] },
    mediaUrl: String,
    thumbnailUrl: String,
    accessType: { type: Number, enum: [1, 2, 3] },
    tags: [String],
    like_count: Number,
    comment_count: Number,
    share_count: Number,
    insertDate: {
      type: Date,
      default: () => {
        return new Date();
      }
    }
  });`
- Feeds: This collection just add a metadata of user and post including tags. This i intend to use to get the relevant feed for a particular user.

  `Schema: 
      const feedSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      post_id: String,
      user_id: String,
      isTag: Boolean,
      isPublic: Boolean,
      insertDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: () => {
          return new Date();
        }
      },
      modifiedDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: () => {
        return new Date();
          }
        }
      });`
- Connects: This collection is for the relationship of users.

  `Schema:
    const connectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        followed_by: String,
        user_id: String,
        insertDate: {
          type: Date,
          default: () => {
            return new Date();
          }
        }
      });`

My approach was to first find the posts from feeds collection basis users whom I am following, then fetching the posts from post collection.
Here goes my attempted query:

```
db.connects.aggregate([
    { $match: { followed_by: "5cbefd61d3b53a4aaa9a2b16" } },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "feeds",
        let: { user_id: "$user_id" },
        pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { $or: [{ $eq: ["$user_id", "$$user_id"] }, { isPublic: true }] } } }],
        as: "feedData"
      }
    },
    { $unwind: "$feedData" },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$feedData" } },
    { $group: { _id: { post_id: { $toObjectId: "$post_id" }, modifiedDate: { $toLong: "$modifiedDate" } } } },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$_id" } },
    { $sort: { modifiedDate: -1 } },
    { $skip: 0 },
    { $limit: 10 },
    {
      $lookup: { from: "posts", localField: "post_id", foreignField: "_id", as: "postData" }
    },
    { $unwind: "$postData" },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$postData" } },
    { $addFields: { userId: { $toObjectId: "$user_id" } } },
    {
      $lookup: { from: "users", localField: "userId", foreignField: "_id", as: "userData" }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        post_id: "$_id",
        user_id: 1,
        title: 1,
        text: 1,
        typeaccessType: 1,
        mediaUrl: 1,
        thumbnailUrl: 1,
        insertDate: { $toLong: "$insertDate" },
        like_count: 1,
        comment_count: 1,
        share_count: 1,
        user_email: { $arrayElemAt: ["$userData.email", 0] },
        user_profile_pic: { $arrayElemAt: ["$userData.profile_pic", 0] },
        username: { $arrayElemAt: ["$userData.firstname", 0] }
      }
    }
  ]).pretty();
```

Please share your feedback on:

1. Which index should I use to boost up the performance?
2. Is there is a better way of doing the same in mongoDB. Also if any part of the query can be optimised?